# unsure why kubernetes is pinging postgress for

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

i'm new to kubernetes and i've deployed my own version of postgres on it (using `docker-desktop` as a start for learning)

it is up and running and i can connect to it with `pgadmin` or `datagrip`. it is also running with `ssl` and a different postgres username , initial database. IE: its not the default `postgres` username, and not the default `postgres` database. i've changed it for testing and learning purposes.

typically i'll connect to it like this: `psql -U myPgUser -d myPgData`

**my qns**

what i'm having trouble understanding is, i've noticed the logs produces such `FATAL` errors:

```
...
...
2023-04-29 08:56:57.088 GMT [6361] FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.65.4", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption
2023-04-29 09:33:48.919 GMT [8402] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2023-04-29 09:33:49.588 GMT [8404] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2023-04-29 09:33:50.357 GMT [8406] FATAL:  unsupported frontend protocol 65363.19778: server supports 3.0 to 3.0
2023-04-29 09:33:50.654 GMT [8410] FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.65.4", user "postgres", database "template0", no encryption
```

upon investigating it further, it seems like it is resources from `kube-system` that is pinging postgres.

```
>>> k get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
kube-system   etcd-docker-desktop                      1/1     Running     16 (3h12m ago)   20d     192.168.65.4   docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-docker-desktop            1/1     Running     16 (3h12m ago)   20d     192.168.65.4   docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-docker-desktop   1/1     Running     16 (3h12m ago)   20d     192.168.65.4   docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-vd4fz                         1/1     Running     16 (3h12m ago)   20d     192.168.65.4   docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-docker-desktop            1/1     Running     16 (3h12m ago)   20d     192.168.65.4   docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
```

pg_hba.conf looks like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256     # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256     # IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256     # IPv6 local connections:
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
hostssl all             all             0.0.0.0/0               scram-sha-256 clientcert=verify-ca      # IPv4 remote connections for authenticated users
hostssl all             all             ::/0                    scram-sha-256 clientcert=verify-ca      # IPv6 remote connections for authenticated users
```

so from the looks of the postgres log file, it seems like something from here is pinging postgres. my question is, why is that the case? and if its required, how should I be modifying which resources (if i intend to not use the word `postgres` as the default username and database name?)

note: i'm fairly new to kubernetes, so my deployments and all are as basic as most guides online. especially in terms of setting up of `ssl` connectivity on `postgres`

Comment: `jake wong` is your issue resolved..? revert back if you still required some assistance

Answer (score 0):

These two errors are discussed as two different stack questions and they are not related to kubernetes.

**Error 1: FATAL: unsupported frontend protocol 65363.19778: server supports 3.0 to 3.0**

As per this  [document](https://pganalyze.com/docs/log-insights/connections/C31) by pganalyze

> This error message indicates that the client requested a Postgres
> FE/BE protocol version that the server does not support. The most
> likely explanation for this is programs accidentally connecting to the
> Postgres port and not writing the correct protocol structure. You may
> also see this when someone runs a port scanner against your database
> server.

**Error 2: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.65.4", user "postgres", database "template0", no encryption**

This error mostly occurs when you haven’t added proper permissions or entities in the pb_hba.conf file. In general the syntax should be in the following way

```
host          database  user  IP-address  IP-mask      auth-method  [auth-options]
```

For more information on the pb_hba.conf file and what each config parameter is responsible for, go through this [document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).